# importing required module

Tags: python

The following code is working as expected. But I have 2 questions.

```
# import datetime # does not work
from datetime import datetime
row = ('2002-01-02 00:00:00.3453', 'a')
x = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

1) Why does only import datetime does not work?

2) How do I know to which module does the 'strptime' method belogs to?

```
>>> help('modules strptime')
```

does not provide the info I am looking for.

Comment: You know what `strptime` belongs to because the code tells you: it's attached to `datetime`, which you've just imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you do:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

or you do:

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 datetime
```

Is a module. It also has a member named **datetime** which has a method named **strptime**

Answer (score 2):

1) It works fine. But the `datetime` class within  is separate. You need to refer to it as `datetime.datetime`.

2) Use the [General Index](http://docs.python.org/genindex.html). But methods belong to objects, not modules.

Answer (score 2):

The method is `datetime.datetime.strptime`, and when you do a simple `import datetime`, you are only importing the top level module, not the `datetime` *class*

You can test this out like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'dat
etime': <module 'datetime' (built-in)>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}


>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'dat
etime': <type 'datetime.datetime'>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

You can see that there are two different objects in your namespace.

For your second question Python's built-in `help()` only works for those modules and objects that are loaded. If you didn't `import datetime`, `help()` can't help you. So its best to browse the documentation for this; and a google on `python strptime` generally lands you at the correct documentation page.